# CSS3 "plus" icon with box-shadow that doesn't overlap

Tags: pseudo-element, css

I've been playing around with making shapes in CSS. I'm finding that it's all fine and dandy until you want to add a `box-shadow` or `border` to your element that was created with both a `::before` and `::after` pseudo element.

Here's an example I put together of a plus (+) icon made with two elements. I'm attempting to put a `box-shadow` on both the elements, but of course don't want the top most element's (`::after`, in this case) shadow to overlap the bottom element.

http://codepen.io/trevanhetzel/pen/Gsurk

Has anyone found any clever tricks around this?

Here's the code, by the way (Sass and Compass FTW!)

```
<a class="add"></a>

.add {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 2em;
  background: green;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: 25%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    @include box-shadow(-2px -2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75));
  }
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 45%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 10%;
    background: #fff;
    @include box-shadow(-2px -2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75));
  }
}
```

Which outputs something like this: [http://t.hetz.co/Rpne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9qte.png)

Comment: why not use a font icon, which supports a lot more shapes the easy way, and you can shadow and color all you want without headaches. A great tool I love is http://icomoon.io/app/

Comment: I'm just playing around with CSS :) And I have a project that has like two icons and doesn't have to support older browsers, so I'd rather save myself some HTTP requests and font files and just use the power of CSS. And +1 to icomoon.io, if I would have needed a custom font library that's my choice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has poor browser support at the moment but the filter:dropshadow property can be used

```
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 0px 1px black);
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow(4px 0px 1px black);
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 0px 1px black);
```

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/92d56402ea3fe327cb1509d1b894386e)

Comment: EXACTLY what I was looking for. Haven't played around SVG filter effects before, wasn't familiar with this. Thanks a ton!